# How do I interpret the coverage report in python testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have a package and I am retro-fitting unit tests. I have questions regarding the interpretation of the coverage report. The package is organised thus:

```
.
├── application
│   ├── applicationbase.py
│   ├── applicationclass.py
│   ├── applicationuser.py
│   ├── config.py
│   ├── __init__.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── tests
    ├── classes_for_testing.py
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_applications.py
    ├── test_directories.py
    └── test_user.py
```

I run the command in */tests*

```
nosetests --with-coverage
```

and get the output

```
Name                           Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
------------------------------------------------------------
application                        0      0   100%   
application.applicationbase      104     12    88%   197-201, 315-424
application.applicationclass      17     11    35%   267-303
application.applicationuser       20      0   100%   
application.config                42      0   100%   
getpass                          110    110     0%   17-382
------------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                            293    133    55%   
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 26 tests in 0.062
```

The untested lines 197-201 in *applicationbase* are correct, but the module only has 203 lines, so where does the 315-424 come from?

Similarly, *applicationclass* only has 47 lines, so where does 267-303 come from?

Lastly, *getpass* is not in my package so why does it get reported? (It only appears in the report if I use the *username* package)

Comment: What version of coverage are you running? The issue with phantom lines reported is missing lines [is fixed in 4.5.2](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/issues/714)

Comment: @OluwafemiSule Thank you. Had 3.6 installed. Upgraded to 5.2.1 and the phantoms disappear

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I Hadn't realised at the time, but Missing has completely disappeared! Can I get it back?

Comment: Create `.coveragerc` and configure under the [`[report]` section](https://github.com/nedbat/coveragepy/blob/coverage-5.2.1/doc/config.rst#report]) `show_missing = True`

Comment: Mmmm. Doesn't seem to work for me `[report]
show_missing = True`